# Get users that speak specific language from VK

Tags: vk

I want to get list of users ids from VK api. I know city and language that is listed in users profiles.

I know how to get users by city - but what about language? How can i do it using VK API?

Comment: There is nothing about user spoken language in VK API documentation. `users.search` does not provide such paramter. Moreover, it looks like this information is not returned with `user` object at all. At least, I haven't found anything :(

Comment: Try asking this question at Russian SO as well. There is definitely more chance to find an answer there since VK is mostly local for CIS :)

Comment: as i see on this page https://vk.com/dev/fields_2?f=3.%2B%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%2B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%2BM-W langs array is part of user's optional fileds

Comment: I cannot find it in documentation. Most probably, it happens because I use VK in English. English API documentation is not complete, I have already had such problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add atr **lang** in main request api https://vk.com/dev/api_requests

[api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjeWN.png)